# perl and sustitution

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have file:

```
return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec); 
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4),2);
$ld_rest=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total),3);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/12),4);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4),3);
$ld_rest1=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total),3);
$ldec_total_balance=round($ldec_total_debit-$ldec_total_credit,3);
$ldec_debit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_debit",$li_z),2);
$ldec_credit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_credit",$li_z),2);
$ld_total_debit=round($rs_data->fields["total_debit"],2);
```

I want to change all round numeric aproximation to 4, so my expect is:

```
return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec); 
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4),4);
$ld_rest=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total),4);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/12),4);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4),4);
$ld_rest1=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total),4);
$ldec_total_balance=round($ldec_total_debit-$ldec_total_credit,4);
$ldec_debit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_debit",$li_z),4);
$ldec_credit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_credit",$li_z),4);
$ld_total_debit=round($rs_data->fields["total_debit"],4);
```

if I try `perl -pe 's/(round\((.*?),)([0-9])/$14/g' file`
it gives me:

```
return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec); 
$ld_div_asig = );
$ld_rest=);
$ld_div_asig = );
$ld_div_asig = );
$ld_rest1=);
$ldec_total_balance=);
$ldec_debit=);
$ldec_credit=);
$ld_total_debit=);
```

But if add space  at the sustitution part, `perl -pe 's/(round\((.*?),)([0-9])/$1 4/g' file`
it gives me:

```
return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec); 
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4), 4);
$ld_rest=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total), 4);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/12), 4);
$ld_div_asig = round(($ld_assigned/4), 4);
$ld_rest1=round(($ld_assigned-$ld_total), 4);
$ldec_total_balance=round($ldec_total_debit-$ldec_total_credit, 4);
$ldec_debit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_debit",$li_z), 4);
$ldec_credit=round($this->ds_Prebalance->getValue("total_credit",$li_z), 4);
$ld_total_debit=round($rs_data->fields["total_debit"], 4);
```

It's what I want but I'd like to get it without the aditional space between the `,` and the `4`.

Is there a way to do the sustitution in perl or sed without adding the aditional space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also write your one-liner as `perl -pe 's/(round\((.*?),)([0-9])/${1}4/g' file` -- that is, write `${1}` instead of `$1`. As you wrote it, Perl reads `$14` as referring to capture group 14.

Answer (score 2):

I moved the comma outside the capture group then added the comma to the substitution: https://regex101.com/r/Exfl2C/1

`perl -pe 's/(round\((.*?)),([0-9])/$1,4/g' file`

Comment: There are too many pending edits so Ill mention in a comment that you could use `s/(round\((.*?)) *, *([0-9])/$1,4/g` to catch whitespace around the comma.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to use `${1}` instead of `$1`.

But a leading (`$&` or) `$1` in the replacement tells us we could simplify our code by using `\K`.

```bash
perl -pe's/round\(.*?,\K[0-9]/4/g'
```

The `\K` "keeps" what the left of the `\K` matched, so only the digit is replaced.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please explain your code?

Comment: `\K`  "keeps" what's on the left. It's not replaced.